# How to list based on two objects in spring jdbctemplate

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I have got 3 tables country, state and city. I want to list cities based on state and country. How to do this in spring jdbctemplate.I tried something like this.But i get type mismatch error.

```
public List<City> getCityNames(String Country, String State){
     List<City> city= null;
     try{
         city= jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT City_Name FROM city WHERE 
                             Country= ? and State = ?", new Object[] { Country, State}, 
         new BeanPropertyRowMapper<City>(City.class));
     }catch(DataAccessException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return city;
}
```

Comment: Did you encounter any error ? If so update the question.

Comment: I get type mismatch error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your query is incorrect. You are asking for city names, but your list holds City objects. Then you should correct that.

Second, you can use the next method:

```
queryForList(String sql,
             Object[] args,
             Class<T> elementType)
                         throws DataAccessException
```

In order to query for your whole City list.

With queryForObject you'll get an actual **one** instance, and not a list of instances.